# flexdashboard and shiny pdf report

Tags: pdf, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I'm new on shiny and flexdashboard.With flexdashboard I've written a .Rmd file to make a nice shiny application (I'm just a statistician).
I want to export some calculations (by a download button)in a report with a  pdf file. In shiny examples, I need again to create another Rmd file, as an example of report.Rmd. I can open my application in the browser, and i'm successful to download a pdf file. But it's not working online (with shinyapps.io). I have two files with .rmd extension, and another one with .r extensions(my functions). Can it be the problem of the two.rmd?Do you Have any idea or example working?
thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the server is expecting the function files (*.R) in a certain folder and you are uploading it to another (or in the base folder).

I believe the convention is to put source files into a sub-folder called "R": `/R/`
If that doesn't work then try `\www\`. This is where icons are normally sourced from.