# Shiny flexdashboard: download Report

Tags: shinydashboard, flexdashboard

i am trying to figure out if there is a possibility to download a report withing interactive `flexdashboard`?

We do have possibility to download a report using `Shiny` (`downloadButton`), however there is **nothing mentioned in the `flexdashboard` documentation about downloading the report** (i have seen only examples for downloading the data etc, which is quite easy).

Sample code from the examples of `flexdasboard`:

````
---
title: "Old Faithful Eruptions"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    social: menu
    source_code: embed
runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
# load data in 'global' chunk so it can be shared by all users of the dashboard
library(datasets)
data(faithful)
```

Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Waiting time between eruptions and the duration of the eruption for the
Old Faithful geyser in Yellowstone National Park, Wyoming, USA.

```{r}
selectInput("n_breaks", label = "Number of bins:",
            choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = 20)

sliderInput("bw_adjust", label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
            min = 0.2, max = 2, value = 1, step = 0.2)
```

Column
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Geyser Eruption Duration

```{r}
renderPlot({
  hist(faithful$eruptions, probability = TRUE, breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks),
       xlab = "Duration (minutes)", main = "Geyser Eruption Duration")

  dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = input$bw_adjust)
  lines(dens, col = "blue")
})
```
````

It would be great if someone could help insert the `downloadButton` which is going to give a pdf report based on `flexdasboard` code.

There has been similat question [to mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40613181/flexdashboard-and-shiny-pdf-report), however noone has answered it.